# What conversion for videos take place when connected to zune for sync

Tags: zune, video

Whenever I record a new video from my phone and then connect it to Zune to sync it, it always shows **converting video** message. What conversion processes are exactly taking place here? Are the videos on phone not stored in .mp4 format that they are originally in?

Also, is there a difference of the size of video synced to the phone and the original on the pc ?

Comment: Can we see your settings? I can't imaging why Zune would do that.

Comment: @Louis, You mean to say this is just happening for me and not all. Do you also use Lumia ??

Comment: Well I wanted to try copying your settings, because I can't find anything like you're describing. I use a Samsung.

Comment: ohh k....I didn't checked zune settings, let me see..I thought this was regular thing for all

Comment: I checked the settings but didn't find anything special.

Answer (score 1):

I know that Windows Phone supports WMV, AVI, MP4/M4V, 3GP/3G2 and MOV (QuickTime). If your camera is on low quality it might be recording in 3GP. Try changing the quality of the camera under settings and connect with Zune and see if it converts.